# Perl. Регулярные выражения. Извлечение подстроки в переменную

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регулярными выражениями. 
С ними я сталкивался только для проверки является ли введеная строка в поле на форме почтовым ящиком, теперь нужно решить такую проблему.
имеется строка из тегов хед

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Нужно значения Content-Type, text/html, windows-1251 сохранить в переменные для дальнейшего использования с помощью регулярных выражений на Перле.
Т.е., чтобы, например, переменная $x была равна ''Content-Type", $y была равна 'text/html', f $z - 'windows-1251'

Буду очень признателен ответившим.
Заранее спасибо!

Вот что сделал сам(
Значит, имеется htmlka. Вот такая 1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 25 Feb 2014 08:21:57 GMT"> 
</head>
<body>
  <p>vacuum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

А вот код перловский:

```
open FILE, '1.html';
while (defined (my $file_line = <FILE>)) 
{
  print $file_line;
  # значением $ct должна быть строка, например, Content-Type
  $ct = $file_line =~ m{<meta http-equiv="(.*?)"content}sx;
  # значением $th должна быть строка, например, text/html
  $th = $file_line =~ m{content=""(.*?)";charset=}sx;
  # значением $chst должна быть строка, например, windows-1251
  $chst = $file_line =~ m{charset=(.*?)";">}sx;
  # значением $expr должна быть строка, например, Wed, 25 Feb 2014 08:21:57 GMT
  $expr = $file_line =~ m{<meta http-equiv="expires" content="(.*?)";">}sx;
}
print $ct;
close FILE;
```

Код выводит только исходный код странички((
А нужно выдрать значения из метатегов в переменные.
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Цель-то какая: удовлетворить препода или разобрать заголовки?

Comment: )
Конечная цель - удовлетворить преподавателя. Курсовая работа - написать что-то типа http протокола, с самими заголовками я разобрался, а вот с регулярными выражениями как-то не очень.((

Comment: У, как всё запущено... Но в любом случае - прямая дорога на CPAN. Если не научит правильные инструменты для решения задач выбирать, то хотя бы поразглядывать потроха какого-нибудь [HTTP::Message](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Message.pm) и всего что вокруг - полезно будет.

Comment: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380 - не перл, но регулярка пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот накидал вам

http://regex101.com/r/oV6wO9

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $rx=q~equiv=.*?(Content-Type).*content=.*?([a-zA-Z\/]+).*charset.*?([a-zA-Z\-\d]+).*?>~;

my $html=<<HEREDOC;
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 25 Feb 2014 08:21:57 GMT">
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>vacuum</p>
      </body>
</html>
HEREDOC

if ($html=~/$rx/) {
        print join "\n",$1,$2,$3

}
```

Comment: Антон, спасибо большое за оперативный ответ.
Не подскажете, как теперь то, что вами составленная регулярка отобрала, сохранить в переменные в перле?

Comment: Как-то так:

    my $tree = new HTML::Tree;
    $tree->parse_file( 'index.html' );
    my @all_metas = $tree->look_down( '_tag' => 'meta' );
    print Dumper( $_->attr('content') ) for @all_metas;

Comment: @klopp, верно конечно, но в учебных заведениях дистрибутив перла установленный на компах зачастую заключется в одном файле perl.exe на винде ))

Comment: Антон, да ты крут! Очень выручил! Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте массив `@ct`, а не скалар `$ct`.

Кроме того Вы обрабатываете строки файла в цикле по одной, и последняя строка, в которой нет образца `"<meta ..."` затрет ранее найденное значение.